# MIMO state space <--> MIMO transfer function - How?

Tags: linear-transformations, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, canonical-transformation

Normally I use the controllability and observability canonical forms to transform a transfer function into a state space model.

I also find the poles, zeros and gain from a state space model to transform the transfer function into a transfer function.

But this is only in SISO-case. How would it be if I have a MIMO state space model and I want to transform that into a MIMO transfer function matrix?

I know that if the column length of the $B$-matrix is $2$ and the row length of $C$-matrix is $2$, then I will have a transfer function matrix of the dimension $2 \times 2$.

So can I still use the controllability and observability canonical forms to compute the MIMO transfer function matrix, into a MIMO state space model, just by using only one column of $B$-matrix and one row of the $C$-matrix at each time?

And if I want to transform a MIMO state space model into a MIMO transfer function, I need to find the poles, zeros and gain for each row and column from $C$ and $B$ matrix?

Are that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical algorithm is *Numerically stable algorithm for transfer function matrix evaluation* by Varga, Sima [DOI:10.1080/00207178108922980](https://doi.org/10.1080/00207178108922980) which can be summarized as iterating
over every row/cols of $B$ and $C$ to get SISO Transfer representations
via $c_i(sI-A)^{-1}b_j+d_{ij}$. Individual elements would be minimal (if the original model was minimal to start with) but it does not guarantee the minimality of the overall model as there can be cancellations with transmission zeros.

I've implemented this [here](https://github.com/ilayn/harold/blob/master/harold/_classes.py#L2695-L2820) for some time ago. I already see that I have to refactor some parts of it apparently.

Comment: But can I not use the connicial forms to do that?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson The canonical form works for SISO or SIMO systems. For MIMO systems you are not guaranteed to bring it to the required form. Think of the B matrix. You have an A matrix in the companion form. Then where should the entries of B at each column should go? All at the bottom? But that can't happen if B is not rank 1 matrix.

Comment: @Precusse Ok! I will try that numerical method to find the MIMO state space model of MIMO transfer function.

Answer (score 4):

For any continuous time state space model, so SISO, MISO, SIMO or MIMO you can always use the following formula to convert the state space model into a transfer function matrix

$$
G(s) = C (s\,I - A)^{-1} B + D.
$$

Comment: How do I do that numericaly ?

Comment: It probably not working to do numerical computations with it?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson In order to evaluate this numerically you would need to be able to calculate the determinant and adjugate of $s\,I - A$. Both require determinants which is the same as the characteristic polynomial. So it maybe possible to solve it with solving a generalized eigenvalue problem of $\lambda\,E-F$, since it would be just a product $s$ minus the eigenvalues. But if $E$ is singular then you would also need to find a gain. And for this I am not totally sure how to find that.

Comment: Well, I think I need to be glad if I can at least SS -> TF in MIMO case now. I use zpk values from MIMO SS to create my mimo TF

Answer (score 1):

If you realize a MIMO linear system channel-by-channel using canonical forms for each pair of 1 input variable to 1 output variable, the realization may be of larger order than the minimum. This subject is covered in Linear System Theory, 2/e - Rugh, Wilson J, Chapter 13, and many other books.

Comment: You mean that I can use canonical forms to generate a MIMO State space model to transfer function matrix just by takeing column against rows for B and C matrix?

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem ! Is that a good book for theory ? When I mean theory, I mean that the book describe the methods so good, that it can be a reference for matlab control toolbox?

Comment: No, you should not realize an p by q MIMO system as pq SISO systems. You can do it, but realization may not be controllable or observable.

Rugh is a good book. Perhaps others are more detailed, such as CT Chen's or Kailath's.

Comment: I am only converting SS to TF.

Comment: That's the opposite of what you wrote before.

Comment: But I going to convert TF to SS using Kung's IR identification.

Comment: Please, Can you show me how to MIMO TF -> MIMO SS using the canonical forms? I already know how to do SISO TF -> SISO SS.

Comment: Hi. Did try to convert MIMO TF to MIMO SS. Did not work by using the forms.

Comment: Try to do it using the forms in textbooks such as the ones I suggested. You won't find a better or more succinct explanation.

Comment: you talking about the connocial forms? I tried that and I end up with a MISO SS, even if I have  MIMO TF matrix or SIMO TF matrix.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I just say that you cannot use the canonical forms to convert a TF matrix into a MIMO state space model. If you have a 2x2 TF matrix, you probably assume that you will get a 2 inputs and 2 outputs state space model. No it won't work like that. The canonical form will give you a MISO state space model, not MIMO. @Pait